# Rails where.not with multiple arguments

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, where-clause

I have an array of ID's I would like to preserve and then delete the rest, we have 3 types of users, `Admins`, `Investors` and `Students`. The list I have is for `Students` id's, so I would like to delete all .

If I try run this

```
User.where.not(id: GOOD_LIST).count(:all)
```

I will get 15k records. but if I try add an additional condition

```
User.where.not(id: GOOD_LIST).where(type: "Student").count(:all)
or
User.where.not('id IN ? AND type = ?', GOOD_LIST, "Student").count(:all)
```

It will return 0 records.

I tried just using the where method

```
User.where('id NOT IN ?', GOOD_LIST).where(type: "Student").count(:all)
```

but got the following error message

```
(10.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."type" = 'Student' AND (id NOT IN 39999,40000,40001,40002,40003,40004,40005,40006,40007,40008)
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "39999"
LINE 1: ...  WHERE "users"."type" = 'student' AND (id NOT IN 39999,4000...
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: how about `.where('id NOT IN (?)', GOOD_LIST)`?

Comment: have u tried this `User.where("id NOT IN (?) AND type = ?", GOOD_LIST, "Student").count`

Comment: Also, is it `"student"` or `"Student"` in the db?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Your first comment should fix it. While using `IN`, we need to use like `(?)`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Is correct, And you can write the same code as `User.where.not(id: GOOD_LIST).where(type: "Student").count(:all)`

Comment: @ArupRakshit: but that's what he tried (the second attempt)

Comment: Thanks guys the `(?)` worked! man I feel like a chop. I have been staring at this for too long. I need some coffee! create an answer and ill upvote it.

Comment: Another possibility is that all of the students are in the good list :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, the second attempt was logical error, not the syntax error.. I am talking about syntax error issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That generated SQL is missing parentheses around the list. So we should add them in your template, like this

```
.where('id NOT IN (?)', GOOD_LIST)
```